# og:image tag in Magento2 cms_index_index.xml (developer mode)

Tags: magento, magento2

When I try to include :

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/DEFAULTIMAGE.png" />
</head>
```

In the xml file "cms_index_index.xml" it gives an error:

> 1 exception(s):
>       Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'meta', attribute 'property': The attribute 'property' is not allowed.
>       Line: 743

I want the meta tag to be inside head tag.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is the attribute is not valid , just use "name" attribute...

```
<head>
    <meta name="og:image" content="http://example.com/DEFAULTIMAGE.png" />
</head>
```

The tag is displayed now :)